# When a user logs in with Oauth 2.0, can the site then send emails from the email adress of the user?

Tags: google-oauth

When you use Oauth 2.0 on your site and users log in with their Google account, is it possible to ask permission from the user to send an email from their email account to all their contacts?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via the read/write access email scope: https://mail.google.com/

Check out the [Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol) for details on how to access the Gmail API.